# New laptop battery charging only until 37% and keeping alive after reaching 0%

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I just bought a new battery for my laptop (Sony VAIO). When I plugged it the first time it was 66% charged. I use it until I reached 5% and after that I started charging it. It just got charged until 46%, after one or two more iterations of the same process, it only charges now until 37%.

The funny thing is that when it reaches 0%, I am able to use the battery like half an hour more. Is like the charging values have been shifted (from 100% to 37% and from 0% to negative value) weird isn't it?

Has anybody seen this behavior before that can make some suggestion on how fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I purchase a "new" laptop battery  before off Amazon.  It did exactly what you describe.  After 2 full charging cycles the thing wouldn't hold more then an hour charge.  I returned it as being defective.  Unless you purchase the battery from Sony I suggest you do the same.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I'm afraid I'll have to do the same :(

Comment: Simply return it.  Find another battery.  The non-oem batteries can work just purchase through say Amazon, allowing you to return it, worth the savings.  I purchase two batteries in my case, from two different sellers, attempted to increase my chances they would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Since the hardware is changed, the system settings for battery may have become obsolete which would cause your system's weird behavior. Perhaps an OS re-install or even better, a driver re-install as [Saurabh Sharma](https://superuser.com/users/293416/saurabh-sharma) suggested would fix this.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have thought about it, but I'm lazy about reinstalling OS. It is behaving the same in both OS on my PC (Ubuntu and Windows) I'll try reinstalling Ubuntu to see what happens. I'll let you know. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @PauloBu Perhaps you may check to see what it's like on a live ubuntu from flash drive without re-installing any OS?

Comment: Great suggestion, it makes more sense.

Comment: @PauloBu I don't think that you need an OS Reinstall Goto `Device manager > Batteries >` Uninstall all of them and Reboot your laptop. If there was any driver/hardware issue, It'll be fixed.

Comment: Sadly I tried both approaches, Device Manager and Live USB Ubuntu and neither work. I think the battery is broken :(